# Launching a CREATE INDEX ON when the index already exists, in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

What happens if you replay a CREATE INDEX ON command on a Neo4J database that already has this index.
Does Neo4J simply ignore that command?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you will execute it, Neo4j will :

- Create the index
- Create a background job to populate it
- As a query stat, tell you that an index is created

At the second attempt, you will have :

- No error
- No impact on the existed index
- An empty stat for the query (ie. no new index created)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd invocation of the create index will run, produce no error, but also not report the index alredy exists and in the end you will still only have 1 index