# Spring Data Neo4J @Index(unique = true) does not work

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to make userName property in User node unique.
I used below code but it doesn't create a unique constraint in the Neo4j database.

```
@Property(name = "name")
@Index(unique = true)
private String usreName;
```

FYI, I'm using the Neo4j Server version: 3.3.6 (community) With Spring Boot 2.
but if I create a constraint in the Neo4j Browser by myself, it works.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.userName IS UNIQUE
```

Is there a way to force Spring Data Neo4J to create unique properties, without creating them by myself in Database?

Comment: I have successfully integrated Liquigraph that is a tool that executes a .xml changelog with the Neo4j Cypher commands (the one you are using "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.userName IS UNIQUE"). 

Have a look at my answer below and vote it! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to configure the auto index manager if you want the application code create the constraints.
You can find the best fitting option in the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:indexing:creation

Just a note on this topic: Think about the auto index creation like Hibernate's DDL support. It is a helper at development time. You should not use `assert` and `update` in production environments but only `validate`.

Answer (score 2):

### Reason

> In Spring Data Neo4j 4, index management concerns were removed from
>   the mapping framework entirely.

(from [Index Management in Spring Data Neo4j](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.1.0.M1/reference/html/#_index_management_in_spring_data_neo4j_4))

### Solution

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void createIndexesAndConstraints() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Result result = session.query("CREATE INDEX ON :User(userName)", Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}
```

Comment: @HadiMohammadi To your first question: `Neo4jOperations` was deprecated and removed in the meantime. Sorry for the inconvenience you may had. Please execute your index building query by means of a Neo4j `session`. It is reflected in the updated answer now.

Comment: @HadiMohammadi To your second question: You can place the code snippet in an arbitrary class, that is annotated with `@Component`. During the Spring Boot application start the bean is scanned and the method annotated by `@PostConstruct` is run once just after all services initialized.

Comment: @HadiMohammadi To your third question: It is answered in the separated question: [StackOverflow: launching-a-create-index-on-when-the-index-already-exists-in-neo4j)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408327/launching-a-create-index-on-when-the-index-already-exists-in-neo4j).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the mode our auto index manager works in through `application.properties`

```
spring.data.neo4j.auto-index=validate # or
# spring.data.neo4j.auto-index=update
# spring.data.neo4j.auto-index=assert
```

Default mode is `none`. Apart from that, what @meistermeier says applies.

Also, Neo4jOperations was deprecated in SDN 4 something and has been removed in SDN 5. Use `Session` instead for operations "near" the database.

Comment: @meistermeier @MichaelSimons Unfortunately the activation of the auto index manager in `update` or `assert` mode works neither through `application.properties` nor `ogm.properties` for me. Using Neo4j 3.4.7 I get no related warn/info message or exception, the indexes are simply not created despite `@NodeEntity` and `@Index(unique = true)` annotations. It seems as if the property entry is ignored. Executing `CALL db.indexes();` and `CALL db.constraints();` produces no result.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you  @ThirstForKnowledg  for your answer. But I have 3 other Questions:
1- I'm using Spring Boot 2, and I can not see Neo4jOperations in my classpath to import it.

2- Should I put this in my Entity node or in another bean?
3- What about after running my application two or more times? I think it would cause an exception for the second time or more.