# Neo4J - Spring Data - Internal ID vs Spring Data ID in parallel transactions

Tags: neo4j, spring-data

I'm using Neo4J 5.x with the reactive Spring Data repositories and client.

I have multiple nodes inter-related and I'm creating new nodes as information comes in JSON from an external source (e.g. REST API or Kafka Topic)

My issue comes with multiple transactions happens at the same time.

Let's say that I have a node Parent, a node Car and a node Wheel.

When a node Wheel is created I want also to create a node Car and a node Owner on the fly if they don't exist as my message contains enough information.

My problem comes from the fact that neo4j has its own internal ID, and even if I have in Spring Data my unique ID, this is not taken into consideration when there are multiple transactions in parallel.

If I don't have a Car and an Owner, but 4 wheels come in parallel I finish with 4 Cars and 4 Owners with different Neo4J internal IDs but my Spring Data ID is repeated.

If one Wheel comes before and the others after the first transaction is completed, the creation and linkage is correct.

Is there a way for me to generate the Neo4J internal ID?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the ("internal") native ID, which is a not a completely reliable way to determine uniqueness. The issue is that you can try to create the same entity concurrently. Can you show your code so it is clearer what is happening? Also, do you have a [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) on `Wheel(id)`, where `id` is the property with the "Spring Data ID"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I will check the uniqueness constraint in Spring Data, I'll build a PoC with the same use case as my current code cannot be shared. I defined the Ids with the Id annotation from Neo4J. I understand that you refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318952/spring-data-neo4j-indexunique-true-does-not-work